# How to create this type of layout without changing the header size

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create this type of layout, here is the image.

[image]

**What I tried-**

here is my HTML code-

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-4">
      <div class="custom-card give-space">
        <div class="header">
          <div class="logo"></div>
        </div>
        <button id="load">More</button>
        <div class="my-div">
          Some text
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My css code -

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@400;700&display=swap');
html{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body{
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #868686;

}

/* for custom card*/
.custom-card{
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-height: 650px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 250px; /* is this ok?*/
}

.custom-card .header{
  position: absolute;
  top: -30%;
  left: -35%;
  height: 55%;
  width: 170%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #2e71ff;
}

.logo{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: -68px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 40%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #2e71ff;
  webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  border: 4px solid #ffffff;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px){
  .logo {
    bottom: -50px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 32%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1200px){
  .logo {
    bottom: -48px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 28%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 768px){
  .logo {
    bottom: -55px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 40%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 576px){
  .logo {
    bottom: -55px;
    width: 18%;
    height: 33%;
  }
}

.my-div{
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  display: none;
}
.show{
  display: block;
}
```

Js code -

```
$('#load').click(function(){
    if($(".my-div").hasClass("show")){
    $(".my-div").removeClass("show");
  }else{
    $(".my-div").addClass("show");
  }
});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ashisbiswas/rpjk3y46/) code

But the problem is if I click on more button, it will show my-div element, which hight is 1000px (basically this is for example purpose, as my custom-card can increase its height) and the header height also increase and brake the layout. So my question is how to take care of the header section if custom-card increases its height? One more question, set padding-top: 250px; of custom-card is ok, because it can change its height and I want space between header and load more button( it ca be div element which contains some text). thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems to fix your issue on JsFiddle at least:

Lower 'my-div' to the next div like so: (because at the moment it is contained within the 'custom-card' div, therefore stretches it on opening)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-4">
      <div class="custom-card give-space">
        <div class="header">
          <div class="logo"></div>
        </div>
        <button id="load">More</button>
      </div>      
      <div class="my-div">
        Some text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Put your 'my-div' in position absolute (added extra code to make it better to the eye, but that's up to you):

```
.my-div{
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  width: 93.5%;
  height: fit-content;
  padding: 8% 0;
}
```

That fixes your issue at least for the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But position absolute of my-div is not a real solution. Now I am  trying to change the code like the header width above 100% and bottom left and right radius 150px slightly -ve the left property. Now it's look fine